# To stock a variable and to use it as prompt input by bash script

Tags: python, bash

Contrary to the topics I found, I am not looking for a input entered from the user asked by the script interpreted by bash.

Here the prompt is from a python script. Let's call it `script.py`. While let's call the bash script `bashscript.sh`.

In a basic terminal when I launch the `script.py` as `python script.py` I obtain a prompt asking:
`Do you want to confirm? [y/n]`. Naturally I enter `y` or `n` in the terminal.

But how to do it when this previous command is not interpreted in the terminal but in a bash script?

I would like something like the following. Sure this a totally wrong code, syntax and so on, that's just to show the idea.

```
#!/bin/bash
#bashscript.sh

preparedInput = 'y'#to confirm by yes

python script.py <- preparedInput #automatically answers 'y' without the user has to type
```

Is that very difficult to implement so I must change my python source code in order to don't ask via a prompt?

Comment: Is this what you want `python script.py <<<y`?

Comment: @oguzismail yes this is. Thank you very much.